# Integrate $\int{\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^3}}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do I integrate $$\int{\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^3}}dx}$$

Not able to think of a method. Any hint is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Generalization:

$$\dfrac1{x\sqrt[n]{1-x^m}}=\dfrac{mx^{m-1}}{mx^m\sqrt[n]{1-x^m}}$$

Now choose $\sqrt[n]{1-x^m}=v\implies dv=?$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** :
Substitute $u=\sqrt{1-x^3}$